# Entity update or Keyboard commands transferred to the Gaming server?

Tags: architecture, networking, entity-system, client-server

I am working on a research project .

I need to know the network communication in games in large Multiplayer games (Battlefield,GTA 5). Is there some official documentation present for these games?

Does the client(player) send Game Commands to the server which it communicates to all the other attached clients(players)  or instead of commands ,Entity Update is carried forward which is then broadcastto other players?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things are seldom openly documented, unless they're patented. So if you know the company behind the game you're interested you could do a [patent search](https://patents.google.com/) to see if they're using a patented mechanism.

Another possibility is to play the game and sniff your own network traffic. That way you can see what packets are sent from your computer and received by your computer and you can then easily find out which of these belong to the game you play, filter them, and start analyzing their payloads. A great tool for that is [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).